# In NotePad++ find and replace, how would I use what I found in my replace?

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

So I have a regular expression for my Find in NotePad++:

```
request\.POST\["[a-z A-Z _]*"\]
```

It finds what I need correctly. What I want to do is use part of what I have found in my replace. In my replace, I want to use the part in between the brackets:

```
"[a-z A-Z _]*"
```

How would I do that? Thanks!

Edit:

For anyone wondering, this is what I ended up putting in the Replace field:

```
$1 = request\.POST\["$1"\]
```

This would have also worked:

```
\1 = request\.POST\["\1"\]
```

Comment: Nevermind, I figured this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose it in parentheses in your find.

```
request\.POST\[("[a-z A-Z _]*")\]
```

Then use `\1` in your replace.  That will return what was captured by the first set of parentheses.  (Use `\2`, `\3`, etc. if you have multiple capturing groups.

Comment: Yea, this works. NotePad++ also let's you use $1 in the replace. I was using \0 earlier and that wasn't working so I asked the question.

Comment: The first parenthesis is not correctly placed and is currently escaped. It should be revised to `request\.POST\[("[a-z A-Z _]*")\]` :)

Comment: @Jerry I should know better than to trust my eyes when it comes to regular expressions.  Thanks!  :)